# AWS Java SDK 2.0 create a presigned URL for a S3 object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know with version 1.x of the SDK it's as simple as per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)

```
java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long msec = expiration.getTime();
msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Add 1 hour.
expiration.setTime(msec);

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT); 
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL s = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

However looking at the [2.0 docs](http://aws-java-sdk-javadoc.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/) but I can't find anything close to the `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest`.

Hopefully there is another simple pattern for this?

Comment: This might help https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/203

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is now supported for S3's `GetObject`. See [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/services/s3/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/presigner/S3Presigner.java).

```
  // Create an S3Presigner using the default region and credentials.
      // This is usually done at application startup, because creating a presigner can be expensive.
      S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.create();

      // Create a GetObjectRequest to be pre-signed
      GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
              GetObjectRequest.builder()
                              .bucket("my-bucket")
                              .key("my-key")
                              .build();

      // Create a GetObjectPresignRequest to specify the signature duration
      GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest =
          GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                                 .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                                 .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                                 .build();

      // Generate the presigned request
      PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest =
          presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

      // Log the presigned URL, for example.
      System.out.println("Presigned URL: " + presignedGetObjectRequest.url());

      // It is recommended to close the S3Presigner when it is done being used, because some credential
      // providers (e.g. if your AWS profile is configured to assume an STS role) require system resources
      // that need to be freed. If you are using one S3Presigner per application (as recommended), this
      // usually is not needed.
      presigner.close();
```

This is also now supported for S3's `PutObject`. Example [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/203#issuecomment-551270731).

```
S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.create();
PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest =
    presigner.presignPutObject(r -> r.signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                                        .putObjectRequest(por -> por.bucket(testBucket).key(objectKey)));

System.out.println("Pre-signed URL to upload a file to: " + 
                   presignedRequest.url());
System.out.println("Which HTTP method needs to be used when uploading a file: " + 
                   presignedRequest.httpRequest().method());
System.out.println("Which headers need to be sent with the upload: " + 
                   presignedRequest.signedHeaders())
```

Here's an example of uploading to S3 using a PresignedPutObjectRequest:

```
PresignedPutObjectRequest presignedRequest = ...;
SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();

ContentStreamProvider contentToUpload = () -> new StringInputStream("Hello, World!");
HttpExecuteRequest uploadRequest = HttpExecuteRequest.builder()
                                                     .request(presignedRequest.httpRequest())
                                                     .contentStreamProvider(contentToUpload)
                                                     .build();

HttpExecuteResponse response = httpClient.prepareRequest(uploadRequest).call();
Validate.isTrue(response.httpResponse().isSuccessful());
```

Comment: For region configuration and credential provider it's similar to S3Client with the builder api : `S3Presigner.builder().region().credentialsProvider().build()` for exemple.
See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/docs/design/core/presigners/README.md#servicepresigner

Comment: Does `S3Presigner` have async capabilities? I need to integrated this with reactive spring.

Comment: S3Presigner does not make any network call, so async is not applicable. Reference - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Utilities.html

Comment: @Andreas Frische
Can you please put any reference for this   
```If you are using one S3Presigner per application (as recommended)```

Comment: @javadev see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/20b85aa9530ee9d6b5bd6ff82a96473055b177f6/services/s3/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/presigner/S3Presigner.java#L105

Comment: thank you I know the reference I mean real an example create
```one S3Presigner per application```

Comment: typically that would depend on the rest of your application. e.g. in Spring you would use @ApplicationScope, but you could also use a singleton etc.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Anurudhha in the comment, it is not yet supported in SDK 2.0. Here is the link to the official backlog

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/projects/1

Here is a workaround from the [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/203), which can help you as of now

https://gist.github.com/aaronanderson/f9e2806cc5e2c18fab4d7e60c589d160