# AWS S3 Presigned Url generated shows access denied when using AWS SDK version 2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to generate presigned url to get access to objects in my bucket and have used AWS SDK version 2 for it. I've followed the process as mentioned in the [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html) .

I've used the given dependency:

```xml
         <dependency>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>2.17.136</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My source code to generate the presigned URL is given below.

```java
     public String getTempUrl(String keyName, Long minutes) {
        try {
            S3Presigner s3Presigner = connection.getS3Presigner();

            GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest =
                GetObjectRequest.builder()
                                .bucket(s3BucketName)
                                .key(keyName)
                                .build();

            GetObjectPresignRequest getObjectPresignRequest = GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                                                                                     .signatureDuration(
                                                                                         Duration.ofMinutes(minutes))
                                                                                     .getObjectRequest(getObjectRequest)
                                                                                     .build();
            PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedGetObjectRequest =
                s3Presigner.presignGetObject(getObjectPresignRequest);

            return presignedGetObjectRequest.url().toExternalForm();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Error downloading the document URL: {}", ex);
            throw new InternalServerError("Error downloading the document URL", ex);
        }
```

```java
public class ConnectionProvider {

    private static S3Client client;
    private static S3Presigner presigner;

    @Inject
    @Property("storage.aws.s3.access.key")
    private String s3AccessKey;

    @Inject
    @Property("storage.aws.s3.secret.key")
    private String s3SecretKey;

    @Inject
    @Property("storage.aws.s3.region")
    protected String region;

    public S3Presigner getS3Presigner() {
        if (presigner == null) {

            if (isNullOrEmpty(region)) {
                presigner = S3Presigner.create();
            }

            presigner = S3Presigner.builder()
                                   .region(Region.of(region))
                                   .build();
            return presigner;
        }

        return presigner;
    }


    public S3Client getS3Client() {
        if (client == null) {

            if (isNullOrEmpty(s3AccessKey) || isNullOrEmpty(s3SecretKey) || isNullOrEmpty(region)) {
                client = S3Client.create();
                return client;
            }

            AwsCredentialsProvider credential = StaticCredentialsProvider
                .create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(s3AccessKey, s3SecretKey));


            client = S3Client.builder()
                             .region(Region.of(region))
                             .credentialsProvider(credential)
                             .build();

            return client;
        }

        return client;
    }
}
```

Code to upload to s3 bucket:

```java
 public Document upload(Document document) {
        try {

            S3Client s3Client = connection.getS3Client();
            S3Waiter s3Waiter = s3Client.waiter();


            PutObjectRequest objectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                                                             .bucket(s3BucketName)
                                                             .key(document.getKey())
                                                             .acl(ObjectCannedACL.PRIVATE)
                                                             .contentType(document.getContentType())
                                                             .build();

            log.info("Uploading the document with key : [{}]", document.getKey());

            s3Client.putObject(objectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(document.getBase64EncodedFile()));

            HeadObjectRequest headObjectRequest =
                HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(s3BucketName).key(document.getKey()).build();

            s3Waiter.waitUntilObjectExists(headObjectRequest);
            log.info(("Document with key :[{}] uploaded successfully."), document.getKey());
            return document;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Error uploading the document: {}", ex);
            throw new InternalServerError("Error uploading the document", ex);
        }
    }
```

The upload portion is working fine and it's also generating the presigned url. But when trying to access the url, I'm getting access denied error.

[image]

When I used [AWS SDK version 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) dependency given below and generated url using it, the url is working fine.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.245</version>
        </dependency>
```

I've tried taking reference of this :

[AWS Java SDK 2.0 create a presigned URL for a S3 object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493657/aws-java-sdk-2-0-create-a-presigned-url-for-a-s3-object)

So far I'm not able to generate a valid presigned url using the AWS SDK version 2. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Make sure you [have permissions to actually access the bucket and create resigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#who-presigned-url)

Comment: @wkl Thank you for helping. It was actually permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue was resolved. Posting a solution for anyone's future references.

The issue that I can see with this is while creating S3Presigner instance you are not actually providing the credentials.

```
presigner = S3Presigner.create();
```

If you create presigner instance using this approach, in reality what it actually do is go through all the possible ways of creating presigner instance. For example one of the approach would be to create using IAM role, one would be get the credentials from the config and many more. But it can fail if these are not done correctly. For a better approach what we can do is to create the presigner instance similar to creating S3Client instance.

```
S3Presigner.builder().region(Region.of(BUCKET_REGION))
            .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialProvider).build();
```

And the way to create awsCredentialProvider is

```
AwsBasicCredentials awsBasicCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(SECRET_KEY, ACCESS_KEY);
    return StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials);
```

Collectively:

```
private AwsCredentialsProvider getAwsCredentialProvider() {
    AwsBasicCredentials awsBasicCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(SECRET_KEY, ACCESS_KEY);
    return StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials);
}

public S3Presigner buildS3PresignerInstance(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialProvider) {
    return S3Presigner.builder().region(Region.of(BUCKET_REGION))
                      .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialProvider).build();
}
```